# How can I easily set the default alignment for the contents of a Grid layout?

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently, some sample code might right like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Click me" Name="MainButton" Click="MainButton_Click"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Name="CounterBlock" Text="Count: 0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

I'm looking for a way to set default cell alignments for contents, so I don't have to specify a `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` for each cell:

```
<Grid DefaultHorizontalAlignment="Center" DefaultVerticalAlignment="Center">
    ...
</Grid>
```

or even:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" DefaultHorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" DefaultHorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Am I missing something, or is this not such a straightforward process?  Thanks!

Comment: What about declaring a style as a grid resource?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like ContentAlignment property at Grid level. You can set styles for child elements. 
you can add this to the Grid.

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="alignmentStyle" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource alignmentStyle}"/>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource alignmentStyle}"/>
</Grid.Resources>
```

As you see above, we have to explicitly set Style for each type, as setting for a base type like FrameworkElement alone doesn't work.

This may not be very helpful if you have only few elements. or you have many elements and almost each is of different type.

Comment: +1 for the use of inheritance and implicit styles. Another approach would be subclassing Grid or implementing a custom Panel to arrange the children as desired, but that's too complex for the matter.